# I have an image data and metadata containing the description of the image, how can i use both image image and metadata to train the images

Tags: image-processing, metadata, conv-neural-network

I need to build a classifier of skin lesions and have image dataset along with metadata which has description consisting of the classification. 
any help as to how to match the data and images and use both in training my convolutional neural network

Comment: Could you post a sample or at least the description of your dataset? What kind of attributes does your meta have and what type of classification task are you doing?

Comment: @SaketKumarSingh OP may need a little up-vote for the question in order to be able to post an image.

Comment: @SaketKumarSingh the dataset is images of moles on skin and the metadata consits of from which area of the body the image has been taken, whether it is cancerous or not, patient details like age sex

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are asking how to incorporate non-numeric data in your metadata in the Neural Network you are trying to train. Hopefully, you will find [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns) document on `tf.feature_columns` helpful. It will help you incorporate categorical, ordinal, etc. as numeric columns.

To train the model with both kind of information, one way would be:

1. Apply CNN to your images and get a dense representation
2. Simultaneously, build another NN to pass your metadata through
3. Concatenate the two resultant Tensors from both NNs and then pass it all through a softmax

Hopefully this should help.

Now the above mentioned `tf.feature_columns` is no longer recommended for new code. Instead of this use [Keras preprocessing layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers).